# How can I get long lived access token when I connect Facebook page

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have a Facebook page and I want the long-lived access token when I connect to the page. How can I get long lived access token.

Comment: That is all explained in great detail in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend access-token by [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/).
Steps

1. open that [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) web site
2. paste access-token : you can see expires time (about an hour)
3. press Extend Access Token : it will extend two months
   [image]